Load an existing edge id in Neptune graph
I'm trying to run a python job in python that bulk loads the Neptune graph from csv files. The job loads these files through curl commands using request parameters (as shown below). However the load fails because the an edge id already exists in the graph.
{
    "mode": "AUTO",
    "updateSingleCardinalityProperties": "TRUE",
    "parallelism": "OVERSUBSCRIBE",
    "source": <file pathe>,
    "failOnError": "FALSE",
    "region": <region>,
    "format": "csv",
    "queueRequest": "TRUE",
    "iamRoleArn": <IAM role>,
}

To avoid these failures, I've tried to query the graph for the edge id before loading it but the data I need to load is very large and the job takes more than a day to complete. Is there an alternative solution where these edges are either overwritten or if an edge id already exists it ignores the new one?

An error about duplicate Edge IDs should only ever happen if you're attempting to create an edge with the same ID, but different edge label.
There are a couple of ways that you can handle this:

If you don't care what the edge IDs are (if you're generating these using something like UUIDs before writing them into Neptune), then you may want to consider letting Neptune assign these IDs for you.  This is not possible using the Gremlin CSV bulk load format, but is possible using the openCypher CSV bulk load format: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-tutorial-format-opencypher.html.  Regardless of which format you use to load the data, the data can be queried using either Gremlin or openCypher (they are interoperable on the same data).
When using the openCypher CSV bulk load format, you can then make use of the userProvidedEdgeIds parameter when issuing the bulk load job.  Set that to False and Neptune will generate the IDs for you.

Alternatively, you can issue the entire bulk load and allow the loader to accumulate the errors generated by duplicate edge IDs.  When setting the failOnError parameter to false, Neptune will continue to load the remaining data as errors are collected.  Once the job completes, you can then go back and query for the errors in the job logs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/load-api-reference-error-logs-examples.html) and address the duplicate IDs individually (perhaps just via queries or by creating a new CSV file and issuing another bulk load job).



Thank you for your response. I do have failOnError set to False. This ends up failing the job entirely because of this error. Is this expected? (My understanding was that some when the load of some values fail, the job still succeeds)
